# Web Hosting of Django Application

Tags: python, django, installation, web-hosting

I found a nice project management app written in Django ([busylissy.com](http://busylissy.com)). Unfortunately, the guys write there at the top that they plan to shut it down and published it as open source for further development. I was thinking of hosting it on ixwebhosting.com with the basic linux program, but I'm not sure whether this is even possible, so that's basically the question.

I only have the access to the basic configuration, so I can't really install anything on that server. In the requirements.txt, the app lists following :

```
 # **Django**
 Django==1.1

 # **Imaging**
 http://effbot.org/downloads/Imaging-1.1.6.tar.gz

 # **STDImage**
 -e git+git://github.com/gearheart/django-stdimage.git#egg=stdimage

 # **Django AuthOpenID**
 -e hg+https://wunki@bitbucket.org/benoitc/django-authopenid#egg=django_authopenid

 # **Django registration**
 -e hg+https://wunki@bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration#egg=registration

 # **Tagging**
 -e svn+http://django-tagging.googlecode.com/svn/trunk#egg=tagging

 # **Authority**
 -e hg+https://wunki@bitbucket.org/jezdez/django-authority#egg=authority

 # **Filebrowser**
 -e svn+http://django-filebrowser.googlecode.com/svn/trunk#egg=filebrowser

 # **Markdown**
 -e git+git://gitorious.org/python-markdown/mainline.git#egg=markdown

 # **Treebeard**
 -e svn+http://django-treebeard.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/#egg=treebeard

 # **Locale url**
 -e svn+http://django-localeurl.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/#egg=localeurl

 # **Thumbnail**
 -e hg+https://sorl-thumbnail.googlecode.com/hg/#egg=sorl-thumbnail

     # **DateUtil**
 http://labix.org/download/python-dateutil/python-dateutil-1.4.1.tar.gz
```

Is there any chance to build a self-contained version with all these prerequisites included that doesn't require much more than mod_python or should I rather start looking for some other tool ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use virtualenv (http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv)

Answer (score 0):

It has dependencies that require compiled code (such as PIL). I'm not really sure what the 'basic linux program' is all about, or what you mean by 'self contained', but it would be trivial to install these dependencies on any normal linux machine. You would have trouble on some shared hosting platforms that do not have the compiled libs available and do not allow you to add your own, etc.

Also don't use mod_python, use [mod_wsgi](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/)

Comment: actually, it's a shared hosting platform, dedicated linux server costs much more (I can imagine there it's fairly trivial to install anything)

Comment: I am unsure of your linux admin capability but I recommend linode.com - seems cheaper than ix. Also, not sure what you mean by self-contained, but maybe a virtualenv is what you're looking for?